# Cloudfront domain name does not work after propagation

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have used Elastic Beanstalk to serve my application.I have created a CF domain with custom SSL certificate with origin as the ELB. I have set the **Origin Protocol Policy** as **'HTTP Only'** and the **Viewer Protocol Policy** as **HTTP and HTTPS**. The CF url works fine after it is deployed and gets redirected to the abc.example.com. But after the CF url is added as CNAME to abc.example.com in the Cpanel server, it shows 'Redirected too many times' error.

Comment: can you show all setting which you trying. and you have to move domain to aws to use CF configuration.